# OMS reports DocumentDb listKeys failure

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, oms

We have a weird error reported by OMS that we cannot track down. I've looked for documentation on this error with no luck.

The error reported by OMS is:

```
OperationName:      Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/listKeys/action
Level:              Error 
ActivityStatus:     Failed 
ActivitySubstatus:  499
ResourceGroup:      Our own Azure hosted API
Category:           Administrative
HTTPRequest:        { "clientRequestId": "[]", "clientIpAddress": "[]", "method": "POST" }
Properties:         { "statusCode": "499", "serviceRequestId": null, "statusMessage": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"ClientClosedRequest\",\"message\":\"The connection has been closed by the client while the server is still processing its request for 'Microsoft.DocumentDB'.\"}}" }
ResourceProvider:   Microsoft.DocumentDb
SourceSystem:       Azure
Type:               AzureActivity
```

It seems like DocumentDb tries to grab information about the Azure subscription and fails ("The connection has been closed by the client while the server is still processing its request for 'Microsoft.DocumentDB'.").

This error occurs now roughly twice a week, doesn't seem to do anything but is reported by OMS as critical.

If anyone has information on this error or experience with it I would greatly appreciate some intel on it.